# How to ask exim4 to redirect some email pattern to a specific email address?

Tags: debian, smtp, rewrite, pipe, exim

I would like to redirect all email from

```
*@domain.fr to username@gmail.com
```

Do you know how I can configure my exim4 server on Debian to do so ?
(My exim configuration seams to be split in different files)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create `/etc/exim4/conf.d/router/350_domain_redirect` and use the following contents:

```
domain_fr_redirect:
   driver = redirect
   domains = domain.fr
   data = username@gmail.com
```

This will work, but is very specific to your problem. An improvement would be to look up the information from a file.

As for everything being in separate files, you can make the Debian exim4 packages use a single file by running:

```
# update-exim4.conf --keepcomments -o /etc/exim4/exim4.conf
```

If the exim4.conf file exists, then it will use that, otherwise, it will use the autogenerated file in /var/lib/exim4.